# kernel reports ACPI Error when bringing network card up or down

Tags: kernel, logs, network-interface, acpi, dmesg

I get these errors in my logs, when bringing my network interface `eth0` up or down, using `ifup` and `ifdown`:

```
kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: NIC Link is Down
kernel: ACPI Error: Index value 0x0000000000000083 overflows field width 0x7 (20200925/exfldio-309)
kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \NEVT due to previous error (AE_AML_REGISTER_LIMIT) (20200925/psparse-531)
kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_AML_REGISTER_LIMIT) (20200925/psparse-531)


kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
kernel: ACPI Error: Index value 0x0000000000000083 overflows field width 0x7 (20200925/exfldio-309)
kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \NEVT due to previous error (AE_AML_REGISTER_LIMIT) (20200925/psparse-531)
kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_AML_REGISTER_LIMIT) (20200925/psparse-531)
```

The network seems to work fine, as far as I can tell. But what do these errors mean, and how can I solve this problem?

I am using Debian 10, and my network card is using the e1000g Gigabit Ethernet driver.

I am using self-compiled kernel 5.10. If these are just harmless messages that come from some too verbose logging, i would me happy to patch the kernel, if somebody can point me to the right place in the code.

These messages are annoying because they are polluting my logs

Comment: Most ACPI errors are harmless. Unless something is not working you can probably ignore them. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333069/acpi-error-on-every-boot

Comment: As far as I know it is impossible to answer this question just from this log. There might be thousand of causes and as @PonJar said, during boot-time these errors are harmless. If possible, try updating your BIOS or Firmware ^^

Answer (score 0):

I have found how these log messages can be disabled in rsyslog, so that they are not logged. This can be added to /etc/rsyslog.conf

```
:msg, startswith, "ACPI Error:" stop
```

while it does not address the underlying issue, it at lease prevents logs from being flooded with useless messages